# .htacsess url rewrite with few pararms

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL

```
 https://exmaple.com/param1/param2/param3/so on .
```

I want url to be

https://exmaple.com/param1/param3/so on .

Here is what i am trying to do

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^param1/param2/param3/$ /param1/param3/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

but above url is not working and redirecting to 404

Any idea

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fussball/land/deutschland/$ /fussball/landing/deutschland/ [L]
</IfModule> this is only in my .htaccess

Comment: Is `https://exmaple.com/param1/param2/param3/so` working fine when you load it in browser?

Comment: yes that is working fine

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^param1/param2/param3/$ /param1/param3/ [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: i have updated the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# match parameter1, parameter2 and remaining URI separately
# capture parameter1 in group #1 and remaining part in group #2
# we are using R=301 to redirect URL externally
# this rule must be placed at the top before last index.php rule
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/[\w-]+/([\w-]+/.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# front controller rule to let index.php handle all non-file/dir URIs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: this is not working. it redirect to 404 page

Comment: @AayushBansal: With these rules in place on my local Apache I get redirected from `/param1/param2/param3/so` to `/param1/param3/so`. What URL did you enter in browser?

Comment: @AayushBansal: Any further updates on this?